# Find the process information with top command in java

Tags: java, linux, grep, runtime

I want to get the process information using the `top` command. I have the below code but it is not working, it just exists the program without any output. My goal is to get the process name, process ID, and memory usage, but that's the later part. For now, I am stuck in getting process information using the `top` command in Java using `grep`.

```
public void getProcessInfo(String processName) {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "top | grep " + processName };
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);       
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

You can make your task considerably easier by avoiding the use of grep, or any piping, altogether.  Who needs grep when you have Java?

Building on arkascha's answer, you could do:

```
String processLine = null;

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("top", "-b", "-n", "1");
Process proc = builder.start();

try (BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(processName)) {   // No need for grep
            processLine = line;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You probably want to skip the summary information and header line:

```
String processLine = null;

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("top", "-b", "-n", "1");
Process proc = builder.start();

try (BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()))) {

    String line;

    // Blank line indicates end of summary.
    while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Skip header line.
    if (line != null) {
        line = stdin.readLine();
    }

    if (line != null) {
        while ((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(processName)) {   // No need for grep
                processLine = line;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome ,i used  the contains instead of grep and it worked thank you VGR and arkascha

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked and answered many times before:

In normal mode the `top` command does *not* output to `stdout`, which is why you cannot simply pipe its output into another CLI utility as you try to do. Instead you have to switch the command to "batch mode" by using the `-b` flag. In addition you have to limit the number of iterations to a single if you want to process the result (no sense for further iterations in non interactive mode):

```
top -b -n 1 | grep "whatever"
```

This is documented on the commands man page: `man top`

Have fun with your project!

Comment: Tried both ways

Process proc = rt.exec("top -b | grep java");

and 

String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "top -b | grep"+ name };

Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

not working

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you also have to prevent `top` from iterating. Again that is documented in the manual page... Hope things work that way for you :-)